# Using Python, how can I turn a text file list into a 5 column data set where some groups of data have less than 5 lines?

Tags: python, text

Most days, I get a list of jobs that look a little like this:

```
 1   Group type 1                       # filename = "280321_AnonymisedTestData.txt"
 2   Job Title A                    
 3   Employer 
 4   Location 
 5   Z hours per week
 6   Job Title B
 7   Employer 
 8   Location 
 9   Y hours per week
10   Group type 1 
11   Job Title C
12   Employer 
13   Location 
14   Y hours per week
15   Group type 1 
16   Job Title D
17   Employer 
18   Location 
19   X hours per week
```

As you can see, most groupings *or sets* of text have 5 lines *or elements*, but some, (lines 6 - 9) have only four elements in their set.

I'd like to put this data into a table and to do this I have decided to put the word "General" on a line on it's own in front of the sets with four elements in them.

So far my 'code' looks like this:

```
with open('280321_AnonymisedTestData.txt') as mylines:
x = 6
while (x < 7):
  for l in mylines:
    if not (l.startswith("Group type 1") or l.startswith("Group type 2") or l.startswith("Group type 3)") l = "General" + "\n" + l
```

and the Output shows a syntax error at line 5 at the point "l = "General" + ..."

*I've got to work out the flow of the program so that the next 3 lines don't get "General" inserted in between them and I intend to put the sets in a data-set,* but for now, can I get some advice on where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're asking us to proofread your Python syntax.  You omitted the colon at the end of the `if` condition.  Also, running such a long line is a bad idea, especially following it with a second statement.

Comment: `l = "General \n"` needs to be on a separate line, and you need a colon `:` at the end of the `if`.

Comment: Thank you @Prune for the pointers and the colon both very helpful.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I did as you suggested and it gave me one word which appeared to be the second to last line of the txt file - interesting. Am trying your code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I despair that people can't reason through tasks like this.  Just do it logically, one step at a time.  What data do I HAVE, what data do I NEED, how do I get there?

```
dataset = []
with open('280321_AnonymisedTestData.txt') as mylines:
    accum = []
    for line in mylines:
        if not accum and not line.startswith("Group"):
            accum = ["General"]
        accum.append( line.strip() )
        if len(accum) == 5:
            dataset.append(accum)
            accum = []

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dataset)
```

Output:

```
[['Group type 1', 'Job Title A', 'Employer', 'Location', 'Z hours per week'],
 ['General', 'Job Title B', 'Employer', 'Location', 'Y hours per week'],
 ['Group type 1', 'Job Title C', 'Employer', 'Location', 'Y hours per week'],
 ['Group type 1', 'Job Title D', 'Employer', 'Location', 'X hours per week']]
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. that works brilliantly. Your accumulator worked much better than my earlier attempts at While. Also I appreciate your logic statements (Have, Need and How).